Paste Button on duble click sometimes shows up as blank
One of my app users encountered this error. When the user double clicked on a text field the paste button which is next to autofill sometimes showed up as blank which is very werid.
I want to know if this is an OS issue or an app issue?
App technologies are expo, react-native
User was using iPhone 14 pro max with iOS 18.1


Everyone has the possibility to see this problem, in every app; it has nothing to do with your app, or programming. See whether the issue continues after an update to iOS 18.2; Apple does sometimes fix bugs (without admitting it, of course).
